# A macro for achieving class level synchronisation within a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I've built this macro:

```
#define STATIC_FUNCTION_SYNCHRONISED \
    static std::recursive_mutex __func__##mutex; \
    std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> __func__##lock(__func__##mutex);
```

Which can be used at the top of a function to achieve class level synchronisation of that function:

```
void foo(void){
    STATIC_FUNCTION_SYNCHRONISED 
    /*only one thread can go here*/
}
```

This is so useful that I suspect that C++11's standard library already has something like this. Am I reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: This is not *that* useful.

Comment: You do know that `__func__` is not actually a macro, and so will not be expanded by the preprocessor?

Comment: I thought it was a C++11 standard macro for the function name

Comment: yes, it is useful. btw `__func__##mutex` is not really needed. Naming a mutex `m` and lock `l` would make that macro so simpler to understand. There isn't anything like that in the standard

Comment: `__func__` is equivalent to `char const __func__[] = "...";`, but provided automatically by the compiler (and not the preprocessor).

Comment: So do you know what they would be expanded to in my function `foo`?

Comment: The variables will simply be be named `__func__mutex` and `__func__lock`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

My boss berated me on this idea anyway and said I should use a template policy class instead.

(But I don't know what that is).

Comment: you can google for "policy-based design" idiom, if you want information about what template policy class means